# What is wrong with my IguanaTex?

Tags: powerpoint, iguanatex

I use IguanaTex to insert formulae in PowerPoint. However, the generated formulae look like this [image]. That is, the box is very long. I do not know why and how to fix this. I attach my code here [image].

Comment: This question could benefit from a description of the desired result.

Comment: I just want to narrow down the box outside the formula. It is inconvenient to have this so  big box there when I try to insert other texts around the formula.

Comment: Try with the standalone class instead of article

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know iguanaTeX but it looks as if it crops the document and documents with `article` have a page number at the bottom which would explain the long rectangle.

Use either `\documentclass{standalone}`, or add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your document.